# Unable to debug .net core2 application over vpn with vs2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-mvc, vpn, iis-express, asp.net-core-2.0

I am able to run my web application on the remote machine (after logging into VM using VPN) without debug but when I try to attach the process I don't find application process to attach for debugging even after I checking the option of show processes from all users.

If I try to start application with debug dotnet.exe crashes immediately, I believe this problem is due to VPN which is blocking the process but not sure how to fix it.

Comment: After I selected the project name instead of IIS Express and updated the launchsettings.json file accordingly I am getting below error:

Unable to start program 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe'.The Visual Studio 2017 Remote Debugger (MSVSMON.EXE) does not appear to be running on the remote computer. This may be because a firewall is preventing communication to the remote computer. Please see Help for assistance on configuring remote debugging.